# Tridion Sites 9.5 Templateless Publishing and Graphql

Tags: graphql, sites-9.5, json

In Tridion sites 9.5 when the component alone ( no template) is published then it push the data in JSON format to the CONTENT table in broker DB. Now how to fetch that published JSON data from the CONTENT table using graphql queries, Is there any better documentation on this how we can play with GraphQL queries once the components are published to CONTENT table without using any template.

SDL 9.5 documentation cover graphql queries for componentpresentation and Pages but not the above case i mentioned.

Comment: If you have keywords or embedded (repeatable) schemas then I would suggest you spend some time reviewing the out of that content using the PCA directly.  Don't under-estimate the amount of formatting (mapping etc.) that is undertaken through the DXA application. I know that in a Tridion Sites Cloud instance, going direct to the PCA is not actually supported at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the **Building a website with semantic content models: a development experience** from TXS NASA 2021. I should give you a useful start.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojPPsrnbQOo